# Pine script loop on bar index

Tags: pine-script

I wanna check a condition for past `n` bars.

So if I want to do it for a specific number, i will use something like this, for 5 last bars:

```
cond = close > open
conditions = cond and cond[1] and cond[2] and cond[3] and cond[4] and cond[5]
```

But i need to use this method inside a function (for custom bar index numbers back)

I mean something like this:

```
check(condition,length)=>
    for i = 1 to length
        condition[bar_index] and condition[bar_index+i]
```

so i can use it like :
`check(close>open,5)`
I expect the answer be true or false.

I've tried many more loops but i can't get the one i need.
Please tell me how to use it in function with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Help (check)")

check(_condition,_length) =>
    _check = true
    for i = 0 to _length
        _check := _check and _condition[i]


cond = close > open
conditions = cond and cond[1] and cond[2] and cond[3] and cond[4] and cond[5]

//bgcolor(conditions ? color.black : na)
bgcolor(check(cond,5) ? color.blue : na)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, just another question, if i wanna use `or` instead of `and` what changes should i do? (i changed the and to or but didn't work well)

Comment: Simply replace `and` with `or` cannot be replaced. It is necessary to understand what is the condition that must be met in general.

Comment: You're right thanks again, Can you please tell me If i wanna start the loop from offset like `condition = cond[5] and cond[6] + ......` (not starting from [0]) How should i change my loop? tnx.

Comment: `for i = _offset to _length+_offset`

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere documented, inline example:

```
close[ta.barssince(time < timestamp("2021-11-07T14:30:00"))]
```